# How to get the ObjectContext container Class name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get the ObjectContext container Class name? without instantiating it like this. `ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;` ..(4 learning purposes)

I know it is the way to do it http://bit.ly/1t38IPd but i want to learn how to get the name.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this right.
Model.Context.cs in App_Code If you are generating t4. if you are not it should be in Model.Designer.cs row 47.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but you can use this:

```
string className = variable.GetType().Name
```